# Postman Client: request body cannot be set (busy indicator shown)

Tags: postman

In the Postman Client I sometimes have the issue that I cannot enter a raw / JSON body value. The usual edit input field is not displayed, and instead an animated busy icon indicator is shown indefinitely.

[image: Postman 'body' field busy indicator]

Selecting a different body type (e.g. form-data) brings the expected input fields, but does not help me. Selecting a different content-type (from the dropdown, JSON in the screenshot) does not help.
Neither does selecting a different verb (PUT, POST, PATCH - even GET shows the same)

I've not found out for which requests this happens, but usually I'm working from a collection automatically generated from our UI documentation.

I'm pretty sure I've seen those working before, but when they don't work, re-opening them from the collection will not help, neither will restarting of Postman client.

I tried searching for this issue both on Postman help, here on StackOverflow, and Google, but didn't find the right search terms to bring up anything useful.

When checking the Postman version, I get this information:

> You are up to date! Postman v8.7.0 is the latest version.

Comment: Have you raised an issue on GH fully explaining the issue? Reporting this directly to the team rather than a question on SO is probably the better course of action here.

Comment: I did not yet, partly because I thought it was some issue on my side instead of a program bug, and partly because I was unaware this is an option.

Comment: If you just open an issue here https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues - explain the problem and give some examples (a short video is always best) then it's put straight in front of the team. You could also drop a message to help@postman.com from your registered account and explain the issue.